# Multi-threading with kivy

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy

I'm writing this code in python using kivy libraries for the UI in which I do some URL requests.
I don't have the code with me right now to share but I'll try to explain it.
Basically, the user types in a text box and clicks a button, which will return a list of names and those names appear in the screen (all of this happens inside a popup).
The thing is, I want to show a spinning ball with a loading message while it waits for the request. I have all the URL functions in a different script.
What I need to do, is to open this second popup, start a new thread for the URL request and let the main thread run normally so the animation shows properly. Then, when the request is finished, close this popup and show the desired results.
Does anyone knows how to call kivys functions from outside the App and/or how to know when the thread finishes?
I'm lost here. Any guidance or example of something similar will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Multithreading in kivy is pretty simple as long as you don't need to update the GUI (you don't). You have to remember one thing - the GUI runs on the main thread and you shouldn't block it. As long as your operation runs on another thread it will be okay.

I used [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Working-with-Python-threads-inside-a-Kivy-application) example when implementing a loading screen in my app.

Now, the hard part is knowing when to close your popup. You can pass a callback function like `close_popup_load_data` when you call your URL function, you can create two threads - one will do the work and the other will check if the work is done (you can check if a thread is alive) and the second one will close your popup and load the data. There are many ways to do this.

Try making something simple first and see if it works.

Comment: Hi, it's been a while since I had to put this part on hold. I didn't get what you said the first time, but now I think I do. 
Anyway, I solved it by sending the popup object to the thread, and closing it from there. I've also send the calling class to the thread to obtain the results. **I know it is not the way it's suppose to be done** but for prototyping purposes it works.
After doing that, I think I get your advice and I'll try to implement it later. Thanks